# How to initialize admin credentials in Firebase cloud functions, using typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was using Firebase cloud functions in javascript. I used this simple looking code to initialize admin.

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(require('./key/firebase-adminsdk.json')),
  databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com"
});
```

The same code does not seem to work in case of typescript. I get this error

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './key/firebase-adminsdk.json'
```

My folder structure is like and the path is correct.

```
├── src
│   ├── keys
│   │   ├── firebase-adminsdk.json
│   |── index.ts
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typescript compiles into a different folder `/libs` and the `./keys/firebase-adminsdk.json` would not be available in it.

I moved the keys folder one level up and modified the code (notice the **../key**).

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(require('../key/firebase-adminsdk.json')),
  databaseURL: "https://app.firebaseio.com"
});

├── key
│   ├── firebase-adminsdk.json
├── lib
│   ├── indexjs
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
```